# Does creating a new account have to be done by another existing account?

Tags: accounts

I noticed that to create a new account unless its created by another **established** account and you cannot do this by yourself if you have EOS from an exchange and want to transfer it out.

Is this true?

Comment: As @confuse00 said you need a creator. You can check this by going to jungle test net and create a new account. After creating a account if you check the history of your transaction you will find that 3 actions are called. you will get cpu  and ram allocation by creator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, besides the first account (`eosio`), each account needs a creator to sign the blockchain transaction that creates the account.

On networks where `eosio.system` has been deployed (e.g. EOS mainnet,) the creator pays for the computational resources necessary for a new account.